# how to get the part of the day from a given 24 hour time format in pandas and python

Tags: python, pandas

Hi I have dataset in which a col value looks like 08:25:00 I want to the resultant value as morning.

```
10:36:00  - Morning 
16:00:00 - afternoon
17:00:00 - afternoon 
19:00:00 -evening
```

I tried with this below steps but for few rows I am getting Nan values and incorrect result

```
df['PNR_CREATE_TM_1']=pd.DataFrame({'PNR_CREATE_TM':range(1,25)})

bns=[0,4,8,12,16,20,24]

part_days=['Late Night','Early Morning','Morning','Noon','Evening','Night']

df['PNR_CREATE_SESSION'] = pd.cut(df['PNR_CREATE_TM_1'],bins=bns,labels=part_days,include_lowest=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming 'time' the initial column as string type, you could split the hours, and use `pandas.cut`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'time': ['10:36:00', '16:00:00', '17:00:00', '19:00:00']})
bns=[0,4,8,12,16,20,24]
part_days=['Late Night','Early Morning','Morning','Noon','Evening','Night']

s = df['time'].str.split(':').str[0].astype(int)
df['part'] = pd.cut(s, bins=bns, labels=part_days, include_lowest=True)
```

output:

```
       time     part
0  10:36:00  Morning
1  16:00:00     Noon
2  17:00:00  Evening
3  19:00:00  Evening
```

Answer (score 0):

Convert values to datetimes by [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) and get hours by [`Series.dt.hour`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.hour.html):

```
df['PNR_CREATE_SESSION'] = pd.cut(pd.to_datetime(df['PNR_CREATE_TM_1']).dt.hour,
                                  bins=bns,
                                  labels=part_days,
                                  include_lowest=True)
```

Or if python object times:

```
df['PNR_CREATE_SESSION'] = pd.cut(pd.to_datetime(df['PNR_CREATE_TM_1'].astype(str)).dt.hour,
                                  bins=bns,
                                  labels=part_days,
                                  include_lowest=True)
```